# Logging into a website and then getting asp data in BeautifulSoup4 in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, curl, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have to do following tasks:

a. Login into a router GUI with user and password

b. You'll land on http://192.168.10.1/index.asp

c. Navigage to http://192.168.10.1/html/common/getneighbourAPinfo.asp and get all data in a json or text file.

I can go directly to the link provided in point "c" if I have logged into the router in another tab. Otherwise it doesnt go ahead.

Is there any way to start a logged in session and then go to the link and get data? All of that in terminal?

Currently I am using pyautoGUI to get data via GUI.